# docker-compose volume on azure storage : how to bind to a file

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, azure-container-instances

I can't get to azure container instance linked a file from my docker to a file that I placed in an azure storage account

the path after the volume name does not seem to be accepted : /conf/nginx.conf

```
volumes:
  - nginxconf/conf/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

here is my docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:
  client:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    volumes:
      - nginxconf/conf/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

volumes:
  nginxconf:
    driver: azure_file
    driver_opts:
      share_name: nginxfiles
      storage_account_name: nginxcontainerstorage
      storage_account_key: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

Answer (score 2):

to solve my problem I modified the systemctl service file to launch nginx by specifying a configuration file in a different location.
and I have a volume where there is the nginx.service and another with my nginx configuration. I mount folders and not a file and it works

my code : https://github.com/auriou/dockerfiles/tree/master/nginx

I had done the test locally and then on azure

Local :

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:
  client:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    volumes:
      - nginxconfig:/etc/nginx/myconfig
      - nginxservice:/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants

volumes:
  nginxconfig:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: "/mnt/c/Users/p.auriou/Documents/GIT/azure/aci/nginx/docker/config"
  nginxservice:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: "/mnt/c/Users/p.auriou/Documents/GIT/azure/aci/nginx/docker/service"
```

azure:  I copied the files to my azure storage

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:
  client:
    image: nginx
    domainname: nginxconf
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    volumes:
      - nginxconfig:/etc/nginx/myconfig
      - nginxservice:/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants

volumes:
  nginxconfig:
    driver: azure_file
    driver_opts:
      share_name: nginxconfig
      storage_account_name: nginxcontainerstorage
      storage_account_key: "XXXXXXXXXXX"
  nginxservice:
    driver: azure_file
    driver_opts:
      share_name: nginxservice
      storage_account_name: nginxcontainerstorage
      storage_account_key: "XXXXXXXXXXX"
```

The systemd file for nginx

```
[Unit]
Description=nginx - high performance web server
Documentation=https://nginx.org/en/docs/
After=network-online.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/var/run/nginx.pid
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/myconfig/nginx.conf
ExecReload=/bin/sh -c "/bin/kill -s HUP $(/bin/cat /var/run/nginx.pid)"
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c "/bin/kill -s TERM $(/bin/cat /var/run/nginx.pid)"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0):

**I have tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the positive results.**

**Note:** In this demo, I have tried to bind **index.html** file to **/usr/share/nginx/html** folder to identify the changes easily.

**Step 1:** Add **docker context** to run docker-compose.yaml in **ACI**

[image]
Refer to this [link](https://docs.docker.com/cloud/aci-integration/) for more information on setting docker context.

To repro your issue, I have executed docker-compose.yaml file with below configuration as like yours.

[image]

I got the below error after running the above code.

[image]

Now, I have modified the above code as below.

[image]

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  client:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    volumes:
      - nginxconf:/usr/share/nginx/html

volumes:
  nginxconf:
    driver: azure_file
    driver_opts:
      share_name: fileshare4dc
      storage_account_name: strg4dc
      storage_account_key: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

**Note: ACI does not support port mapping as of now. Container port and ACI port must be same.**

Now run docker compose and verify the container instance created.

```
$docker compose --project-name nginx-aci up -d
```

[image]

[image]

Compare the files in azure file share and ACI to check bind volume is working properly or not.

Below are the files in my Azure fileshare.

[image]

Below are the files in my Container.

[image]
Commands used in above screenshot.

```
$docker ps
$docker exec -it <container-name> bash
```

Whatever changes or files adding in Azure file share, it will reflect same in container.

Comment: yes it works but it doesn't solve my problem. In your case you linked a folder and in my case it's a file I want linked. Because in the directory containing /etc/nginx/nginx.conf contains other files. So we can't link the complete folder /etc/nginx/

Comment: Two questions for you. (1) Where did you get the plugin `azure_file`?  (2) [docker Office document](https://docs.docker.com/cloud/aci-integration/) said, Docker Compose’s integration for ECS and ACI is retiring in November 2023. Any other solutions?